# keycloak and postgresql on openshift

Tags: postgresql, openshift, keycloak, openshift-origin, keycloak-services

I tried to deploy keycloak with POSTGRESQL on openshift. I used this image, `jboss/keycloak-openshift` image for keycloak and `rhscl/postgresql-95-rhel7` for postgresql.

I then I added environment variables in keycloak deployment

- DB_DATABASE : keycloak
- DB_USER : postgresl-secret-database-user
- DB_PASSWORD : postgresl-secret-database-password
- DB_VENDOR : POSTGRES

I thought this is what I needed to do to make keycloak work with postgresql. These are the errors and warning I am seeing in the pod logs.

`IOException occurred while connecting to postgres:5432: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres`

`Connection error: : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.`

But it is not working this way. The keycloak pod fails. Do I need to do anything else as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the name of your database service?

If not the default of `postgres` that Keycloak expects, you need to set `DB_ADDR`. I use the following in my template:

```
                                {
                                    "name": "KEYCLOAK_USER",
                                    "value": "${KEYCLOAK_USER}"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD",
                                    "value": "${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "DB_VENDOR",
                                    "value": "postgres"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "DB_ADDR",
                                    "value": "${KEYCLOAK_NAME}-db"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "DB_PORT",
                                    "value": "5432"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "DB_DATABASE",
                                    "value": "keycloak"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "DB_USER",
                                    "value": "keycloak"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "DB_PASSWORD",
                                    "value": "${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"
                                },
```

Suggest setting them all.

Further details in:

- https://github.com/jupyter-on-openshift/poc-hub-keycloak-auth/blob/master/templates/jupyterhub.json

Comment: Thanks @Graham it worked. It was the issue with the default db name.

Comment: I am sort of facing this issue again, this time using the new image of keycloak, jboss/keycloak. I don't know what am I missing. The connection with DB doesn't seem to work again. Are there any configuration changes in the new keycloak image?

Comment: This is the error i get. ` Error in url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:tcp://172.30.230.28:5432/keycloak`

Comment: it seems that I made it run, but it is now showing 'Invalid parameter: redirect_uri'.  What is it that I am doing wrong? @Graham